# Macbook Air 2015 won't log in after updating

Tags: hard-drive, startup, install, password

I just wanted to do some software updates on my 2015 Macbook Air, but that did not go well. During the installation process I got an error that said "Error with installation." This was while it was in the installation manager. The laptop shut down and has not worked since. When I turn on the computer normally I get prompted with the normal login screen, but when I log in it loads and then I get a black screen with a white stop sign (circle with / in the middle).

I have tried several things:

1. Boot into safe mode
   When I do this and log in it goes into the installation manager again and I get the same error as before.
2. Boot into recovery mode
   When I boot into recovery mode I get to the screen that says "Of which user do you know the password" and the option of the two users I have to log in. I then try to log in into the main account but it keeps saying the password is wrong (while I type in the correct password). I've tried to log into the other user but same problem occurs.)
3. Boot into single user mode to fix the drive
   When I type in `/sbin/fsck -y` I get the error that there alredy is a drive mounted and therefor it cant perform the repairs on the disc.

I did not make a back up of my data, so is there an option to access my data and put it on an external hard drive or to fix the Macbook so I can use it again? Would a clean install from USB thumb drive of maybe Catalina or Yosemite work without losing my data?